# Creating iPhone — mySQL database communication

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c, ios

My iPhone app has to communicate very regularly with a mySQL database; it both sends requests to receive data and add data to the database.

For now, all my iPhone app does is send a POST request to a PHP script that checks for POST requests and executes queries based on request type. Now, I've read that this is "bad" and I'm a beginning programmer (especially server side scripting), so I would like to know "best ways" or "best practices" to do this.

Is it simply sending in a hashed password to the PHP script so that it checks before running requests, and using SSL? Or is there more to it?

If possible, please include relevant documentation and/or code to get me started.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 fundamental concerns you need to address.  A little googling will get you info on each.
1) Authentication -- Controlling who has access to your web service (depending on your setup, there are many options for this both out of the box and roll your own), 2) Encryption -- Preventing someone from intercepting unencrypted messages to/from your web service (SSL should handle this), 3) SQL injection -- This can be handled server side

Those are the fundamental issues you should be concerned with, and again, there is a plethora of good information on the web for each issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems to solve, rather than one (so often the case in Stack Overflow questions :-)).

Problem 1: Create a PHP web service that allows the appropriate interaction with your MySql database.

Problem 2: Interact with said web service from within your iPhone app.

You'll still need to secure the traffic as mentioned by @wzs, but you've now separated access to your database and access to your service. Only the service can access the database now.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I don't understand what you and other commenters mean by "PHP web service". What's the difference between a "PHP web service" and a simple .php script hosted on a server that handles PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Running queries on remote database from mobile app is not a good idea (no matter if you're using fancy encryption) - in most case, it's a wrong architecture pattern.

Instead you should expose data via REST API (ie. in JSON format). There is a couple of PHP frameworks/libraries which should simplify this proccess, take a look at: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/09/23/short-list-of-restful-api-frameworks-for-php/

On mobile app, connect to the API, parse retrieved JSONs to your business models... 
Libraries like [RESTKit](http://restkit.org/), [AFIncrementalStore](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore), [Mantle](https://github.com/github/Mantle) may be helpful.